# Vacation for 2 weeks out of the USA before applying for N-400, can I still submit the N-400 , or do I have to wait?

Tags: usa, citizenship, us-citizens, residency

If I go out of USA for 2 weeks before applying for N-400, can I still submit the N-400 application, or do I have to wait an additional 3 months before applying?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have resided in the state or service district that you apply for naturalization in for 3 months before filing. (See [12 USCIS-PM D.6(A)](https://www.uscis.gov/policy-manual/volume-12-part-d-chapter-6#S-A).) But a vacation generally does not affect your place of residence. See in particular, [8 CFR 316.5(b)(5)(i)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-8/part-316/section-316.5#p-316.5(b)(5)(i)), which says that your residence, during an absence abroad of less than one year, remains the state or service district where you last resided:

> (i) An applicant's residence during any absence of less than one year
> shall continue to be the State or Service district where the applicant
> last resided at the time of the applicant's departure abroad.

Answer (score -1):

> Can I still submit the N-400 application, or do I have to wait an additional 3 month before applying?

You can still submit the N-400 application, assuming all other requirements are met. The trip doesn't matter.